# What is the difference between ira and furor?

Tags: classical-latin, vocabulary, word-comparison

The words *ira* and *furor* are quite similar, but apparently not synonymous.
I found myself unable to give a clear comparison of the two words.
How would you describe the difference between the meanings of these two words in classical Latin and why?
Especially passages discussing both *ira* and *furor* and their relation would be enlightening.

Here are the translations offered by L&S, which give an idea but not a true comparison:

- [*ira*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=ira&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059): anger, wrath, rage, ire, cause of anger, provocation, object of anger or hatred, violence, impetuosity, fury
- [*furor*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aalphabetic+letter%3DF%3Aentry+group%3D34%3Aentry%3Dfuror2): raging, raving, rage, madness, fury, folly, raging desire, cause of wrath

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Ira* and *furor* are more or less the same as *anger* and *fury* in English. The related verbs *irascor* and *furo* differ to  the same degree. *Furor* has a more physical aspect : if you like, it can be a physically observable quality in its own right.

In the *caeli furor aequinoctialis* of Catullus 46.2, *ira* instead of *furor* would not suggest to me the actual, physical power of the high winds typical of the vernal equinox. On the other hand *ira*, anger, is a more of a sentiment, recognizable mainly by its consequences . According to Horace (Ep 1, 2, 62), *ira furor brevis est*; but I don't think you would say *furor ira brevis est*.

It's no more than barely true to say that the two words are 'apparently not synonymous'. In English you can be *gripped by fury* or *seized by anger*, and you can be either *angry* or *furious*. The difference really isn't very much, and the two are often interchangeable, from Latin into English or *vice versa*. The translation is just a matter of appropriate selection for the context.

Comment: Primarily, "Ira" is an emotion whereas "furor" is a behaviour. However, figuratively, you can, by metonymy, speak of a "furor" raging in your heart, or describe a storm as "ira Deorum", or whatever.